# LinkageError thrown after transaction.commit()

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I am working right now on this ancient legacy code on jboss, but one day it all goes bonkers when we deployed back an old working war file. Even if we revert back to another war file it never goes away (even restart didn't help)

This is the exception thrown after transaction.commit.
`java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/mx/loading/UnifiedClassLoader3) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/hibernate/Transaction"`

I'm not really sure what's going on since it was working just fine before. I am not the one who deployed the war file so I can't tell if he accidentally messed some configurations.

For the version we are using jboss 4.2.3.ga.

I want to know where to start looking and maybe just some clue what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now.

This happened because of the missing hibernate jar in the /lib.

Jboss tried to find the jar with its unified class loader and got something else.

So we just added hibernate-core-3.3.0.GA.jar to lib folder so this jar will be used instead.